# When one has a spouse that they do not deserve him / her

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrases, proverbs

There is a hyperbole which says always a best husband/wife belongs to somebody who really doesn't deserve him/her!
For instance, a quite gorgeous girl with a high educational degree and good family, reasonable job position etc. who has an absolutely average-looking husband who has no property or asset, nothing special in his life, no good job, not a justifiable university degree etc. (The same goes with a husband.)
I wonder if there is any common English proverb / idiom / phrase that can encompass and explain the above fact/belief?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None that are gender specific. "She's too good for him" is possible, but then so is "He's too good for her".

There are related expressions, for example:

> (cast) pearls before swine

Generally this is used when you present something valuable to someone who does not (or can not) recognize its worth, but it can be used in this situation to imply that the man does not appreciate the value of his partner.

Of course, that doesn't mean you can't [write a song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCuMWrfXG4E) about this kind of situation, or create a metaphor.

> She's Dom Perignon and he's Schlitz Malt Liquor.    I don't know what she sees in him.

(Edit)  The metaphor doesn't have to be alcohol-related, it could be anything where one side is if high quality and the other of low quality, e.g.

> She's a ten-carat sapphire and he's just a shard from a broken beer bottle
>
> She's a purebred Russian wolfhound and he's a street mutt with the mange

Comment: She is out of my league. :)

Comment: @AIQ  That's kind of a different situation.  You use that when you like someone who you feel is "too good for you", but you won't ask them out because you think there's no chance.

Comment: Good answer except I am confused by the last bit. Schlitz Malt Liquor. what is this? German whisky or something? and why is the fizzy stuff better than whisky, they are not similar to be directly compared? sorry but this has gone right over my head. Is this an Americanism or German ism?

Comment: @Brad  It's an American brand, but I'm not even sure if many Americans will get it. However you should be able to get the intent from the context.  For general interest:  Malt Liquor is essentially beer with extra alcohol.  It's the kind of alcoholic beverage you buy from the corner store when you want the most kick for the least money, and you don't really care about quality.  I expect this kind of beverage is sold in many countries, under various names, so substitute whatever dirt-cheap brand of alcohol makes sense.

Comment: @A-friend  I can't think of any way to say this in English in a standard way.  The easiest way is with a metaphor of some kind.  It doesn't have to be alcohol-related, it could be anything where one side is if high quality and the other of low quality, e.g. *"She's a ten-carat sapphire and he's just a shard from a broken beer bottle"*  or *"She's a purebred Russian wolfhound and he's a street mutt with the mange"*

Comment: Actually, @Andrew I am not going to compare the wife with the husband **at all**. I'm going to talk about the **chance/luck** of a bad/not-good-looking person and totally someone who really **doesn't deserve** it, where a good "wife/husband" is a good "luck/chance".

Comment: Well @Andrew, what about "he/she is a lucky bugger"? I know that it is applicable for what I need (at least in British), but I need to know how does it sound in American English?

Comment: @A-friend  "iucky bugger" is generic.  It can apply to almost any situation where someone gets good fortune.  Also it's almost exclusively British.  The American equivalent is *you lucky **son of a bitch***

Comment: And what about **"Some people have all the luck!"** @Andrew? Also, the less common expression that is used in casinos: **"Winner takes all."**

Comment: @A-friend  Same thing -- it's generic, but in a positive way.  It indicates *envy* or *jealousy*.    "Winner takes all" is something else.  It refers to the idea that in most competitions, there is only one winner.  Everyone else loses.  It only applies to romance if two or more people are competing for the same romantic partner.